# Only display post if timestamp is from a previous date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I wanted to program posts to be posted on a specific date and time, so I wanted to know if there is a way to only show a post, if the date set on it (on mySQL timestamp) is already gone. This way, if I set a future date on post X (eg.: Mar 30 2014 13:00:00) it won't be displayed on the website until then. However, if I do not set any date, it will automatically set it to CURRENTTIMESTAMP and it will be posted right away.

So basically, what I am looking for is a php code that would filter mysql rows, only showing the ones from a date that is already gone. Any ideas of how I can do this? :o

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than comparing them in php, you should modify sql query to return filtered values i.e `WHERE date_column < NOW()`. Hope you will get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. Simple, and totally works, haha, now I'm ashamed I didn't try that.